# Getting a link from the html using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html

I need to get from an html. That same link appears in different parts of that html. It does't matter to me where exactly is the link obtained from. but it has to be done programly from the html itself. the link i need to obtain is
[Text](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?w0=t&w1=td&w2=wc&w3=sfcwind&w4=sky&w5=pop&w6=rh&w7=rain&w8=thunder&w9=snow&w10=fzg&w11=sleet&AheadHour=3&Submit=Submit&&FcstType=digital&textField1=40.7328&textField2=-73.2177&site=okx). Thank you in advance.

The code I use:

```
    page = requests.get("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?w0=t&w1=td&w2=wc&w3=sfcwind&w3u=1&w4=sky&w5=pop&w6=rh&w7=rain&w8=thunder&w9=snow&w10=fzg&w11=sleet&AheadHour=3&Submit=Submit&FcstType=graphical&textField1=40.7328&textField2=-73.2177&site=okx&unit=0&dd=&bw=")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
    if soup.find(alt="Hourly weather graph of forecast elements. Click for text representation."):
        for i in range(0, soup.find_all('a').__len__()):
            # x = soup.find('a')[i]["href"]
            x = soup.find('area')
            print(x)["href"]
```

it will not interpret

Comment: first of don't call dunder methods like that, use `len` function in this case, second, `soup.find_all` returns a list that you can iterate over, it is really not suggested that you use `for index in range(len(iterable))`, use `for item in iterable:`, you are searching the tags twice, otherwise

Comment: you just want to change `graphical` by `digital`?